# Accessing inner DIV id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code and i need to access the input text field ID here whose class name is "company".

```
 <div class="tabbable">  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">  
   <li class="active"><a href="#overview" >Overview</a></li>
   <li class=""><a href="#addManagerTag" class="addManager" >Managers</a></li>  
</ul>
</div> 


 <div class="tab-pane" id="addManagerTag">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="manager.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- Form Name -->
                    <br />
                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="man_name">Company Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" class="company"  id="{COM_ID}" placeholder="" value="here" readonly>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
    </div>

//i am using following Jquery function
$('.addManager').on( 'click', function( event ) {
  // how can i access the input text field ID here.
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What text field? The input `<input type="text" class="company"  id="{COM_ID}" placeholder="" value="here" readonly>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.addManager').on( 'click', function( event ) {
    alert($("input.company").attr("id"));
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JhZkj/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the you want actual id.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addManager').on( 'click', function() {
        var companyInputId = $('.company').attr('id');
        alert(companyInputId);
  });
});
```

Tested, it works. Kept the alert message for testing purpose.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/komanchero/6vE93/1/)

Comment: In the demo you have linked. both the input types are not in any of the Div fields. I tried that it's not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of the text field

```
$('.company').val();
```

Or if you want to set it

```
$('.company').val("some text");
```

EDIT:

If you want the id itself try

```
('.company').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. it should return the id of the element

```
$('.company').attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the `id` attribute of the element which has the class `company`, that's right?
In jQuery syntax this would be:

```
$(".company").attr("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use a class for that input you can access using:

```
$(".company").click(function () {
       //code
    });
```

or

if you want to use the id you need to change the id of the input to company and use something like:

```
$("#company").click(function () {
       //code
    });
```

I think in this case the parent div is irrelevant.